# split a data frame by group and stack horizontally

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 12L, 10L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "p", "q", "r", "s", "w"), class = "factor"), 
    total = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 6), 
    freq = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 
    0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("X_Group1", 
    "X_Group2", "X_Group3", "Y_Group1", "Y_Group2", "Y_Group3"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Is it possible to convert it like below

```
result <- structure(list(X_Group1.name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), X_Group1.total = c(1, 2, 3), X_Group1.freq = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.3), X_Group1.group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "X_Group1", class = "factor"), 
    X_Group2.name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), 
    X_Group2.total = c(7, 2, 3), X_Group2.freq = c(0.7, 0.2, 
    0.3), X_Group2.group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "X_Group2", class = "factor"), 
    X_Group3.name = structure(3:1, .Label = c("NA", "q", "w"), class = "factor"), 
    X_Group3.total = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("3", 
    "9", "NA"), class = "factor"), X_Group3.freq = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L), .Label = c("0.3", "0.9", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    X_Group3.group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("NA", 
    "X_Group3"), class = "factor"), Y_Group1.name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("d", 
    "e", "f"), class = "factor"), Y_Group1.total = c(4, 5, 6), 
    Y_Group1.freq = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6), Y_Group1.group = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Y_Group1", class = "factor"), Y_Group2.name = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "p", "r"), class = "factor"), Y_Group2.total = c(4, 
    1, 4), Y_Group2.freq = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.4), Y_Group2.group = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Y_Group2", class = "factor"), Y_Group3.name = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 1L), .Label = c("NA", "s", "w"), class = "factor"), Y_Group3.total = structure(1:3, .Label = c("4", 
    "6", "NA"), class = "factor"), Y_Group3.freq = structure(1:3, .Label = c("0.4", 
    "0.6", "NA"), class = "factor"), Y_Group3.group = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("NA", "Y_Group3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I tried split and then bind them horizontally using bind_col and likes but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` after creating a sequence column

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = rowid(group)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = c(name, total, freq))
# A tibble: 3 x 19
#     rn name_X_Group1 name_Y_Group1 name_X_Group2 name_Y_Group2 name_X_Group3 name_Y_Group3 total_X_Group1 total_Y_Group1 total_X_Group2
#  <int> <fct>         <fct>         <fct>         <fct>         <fct>         <fct>                  <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#1     1 a             d             g             a             w             s                          1              4              7
#2     2 b             e             h             r             q             w                          2              5              2
#3     3 c             f             i             p             <NA>          <NA>                       3              6              3
# … with 9 more variables: total_Y_Group2 <dbl>, total_X_Group3 <dbl>, total_Y_Group3 <dbl>, freq_X_Group1 <dbl>, freq_Y_Group1 <dbl>,
#   freq_X_Group2 <dbl>, freq_Y_Group2 <dbl>, freq_X_Group3 <dbl>, freq_Y_Group3 <dbl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun!! That worked... But Is there a way to order name, total and freq of X_Group1 next to each other? Instead of names, total, freq

Comment: I mean name_X_Group1, total_XGroup1, freq_XGroup1, name_XGroup2, total_XGroup2 etc ... 
I have about ~50 odd groups ..Is there a way to automate the order?

Comment: @user11352627 Try `%>% select(ends_with('Group1'), ends_with('Group2'), ends_with('Group3'))` at the end

Comment: @user11352627 did you used `df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = rowid(group)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = c(name, total, freq)) %>% select(ends_with('Group1'), ends_with('Group2'), ends_with('Group3'))`

Comment: Yes I did ... df1 %>%   mutate(rn = rowid(group)) %>%    pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = c(name, total, freq)) %>% select(ends_with('Group1'), ends_with('Group2'), ends_with('Group3'))
Error in select(., ends_with("Group1"), ends_with("Group2"), ends_with("Group3")) : 
  unused arguments (ends_with("Group1"), ends_with("Group2"), ends_with("Group3"))

Comment: @user11352627 could be due to the version?  I used `dplyr 1.0.0`

Comment: I think so..I am using 0.8.3.. I will try updating it. Thank you !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216160/discussion-between-user11352627-and-akrun).

Comment: @Akrun, could you briefly explain why you use `mutate(rn = rowid(group))` in your solution?

Comment: @Mcmahoon89 it is only because if there is no sequence, the pivot_wider generates list columns because there are duplicates for group